# ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG Causing FATAL_ERROR because of Webservice Callout in TestMethod

Tags: apex, unit-test, error

When looking at the debug logs after running some test methods, it looks likes one of our 3rd party managed packages is causing our tests to fail because of a webservice callout in their code.

> 11:54:55.819 (6819107093)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|yw
>
> 11:54:55.821 (6821513067)|FATAL_ERROR|System.TypeException: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts, test skipped (yw)

How could this be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talk to the provider of your managed package. They may have a custom setting or similar that you can set to avoid the callout occurring in a test context. They will almost certainly have some method to do this internally, otherwise they couldn't create the managed package.

Alternatively, you may need to call `Test.setMock()` with a mock for the callout in question.

Finally, if all else fails, you may need to isolate any interactions with the 3rd party package using `Test.isRunningTest()`.